# HTML Preloading of native Webview in Android

Tags: android, webview

I just want to show queue of Webview on screen. To avoid black screen during loading of html in webview, I want to preload webview using z-index or using send to back upcoming webview.....

Comment: and i want to be next president of united states, come on man, put some effort, google is your best friend, if you stuck let us know then and will be more then happy to help you out.

Comment: "`I just want to show queue of Webview on screen.`" What does this mean ?

Comment: @JibranKhan: I mean to say...one by one.....like if 1st html page loaded then html2 after that html3.........so on..........

Comment: What is the trigger point to load new web page ? Some event or ?

Answer (score 0):

this is not the best solution but what with showing Progres dialog for the moment he load the new url ? i

```
  WebView mWeb;
    ProgressDialog mProgress;

  mWeb = your web view id
        // set Javascript
        WebSettings settings = mWeb.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        // the init state of progress dialog
        mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Please wait for a moment...");

        // add a WebViewClient for WebView, which actually handles loading data from web
        mWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            // load url
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            // when finish loading page
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if(mProgress.isShowing()) {
                    mProgress.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        // set url for webview to load
        mWeb.loadUrl("http://www.saharplus.com");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

e.g: you could use like that.

- Add a imageview with full-parent measurement
- Set webview visibility GONE
- Add sample code your activity

  ```
  // OTHER CODE STUFF 
  mWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
           Webview wView=(Webview) view;
           Imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           wView.setvisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
  ```

*typing on phone apoligize for any typos :/